# How do I translate the "Password Strength" , and other texts on Create new Account

Tags: magento2, translate

I would like to translate the

"Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."

"Password Strength: %1"

And other related content on customer/account/create/

How can I do this?

My version is Magento 2.2.3

Thank you,
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have language pack, then you can change the translation in the CSV file 
Mageplaza provide many language pack

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-spanish-language-pack

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack

after installing the language pack, go to the main directory of the pack, then edit the CSV, the file name should be like this [de_DE.csv],[fr_FR.csv]

after you edit the file you need to deploy your static file, the JavaScript translation will be in this file [**js-translation.json**]

> /public_html/pub/static/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/{locale}/js-translation.json

Answer (score 1):

Override `en_US.csv` file into your theme i18n folder.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Comment: by override do you mean replace the content of the en_US file or remove it and copy the new  language?

Comment: @Typo You can create a new file.